# Is it a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

My notes tell me that prepositional phrases are noun phrase preceeded by a preposition. So my doubt is... If you consider this sentence

> the flower in the pot 
>   Is it also a prepositional phrase when a noun phrase precedes the preposition itself?

Comment: No: your example _the flower in the pot_, is a noun phrase where the noun "flower" is modified by the preposition phrase "in the pot".

Comment: Thankyou so much for answering. So is it always accepted as noun phrase if a noun precedes a preposition?

Comment: Yes, because the preposition phrase is part of the noun phrase; it modifies the head noun, and is thus a dependent of it. When the noun follows the preposition, the reverse is true - it is a preposition phrase where the noun is a complement of the preposition, a dependent of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the preposition phrase *in the pot* acts as a **modifier** to the noun *flower*, just as an adjective does: it tells you where the flower is.

So what you have here is a noun phrase (NP *the pot*) inside a preposition phrase (PP *in the pot*) inside a noun phrase (NP *the flower in the pot*)!

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much... I'm glad you know IC Analysis... Would you please tell me what "have been cursing my luck" would be? I can't mark it verb group since an NP also is involved. So is there a specific name?

Comment: @ShonimaNandakumar It depends on what 'flavor' of grammar you're using; terminology is very fluid these days. I'd call that a **predicate**, which would be paired with a **subject**, but many (perhaps most) grammarians call it a **VP**. That name is *derived* from "verb phrase" but it's pronounced "Vee-Pee" and it represents *verb-with-its-internal-dependents*.

Comment: Go on @StoneyB, step up to the plate and give the OP the full catenative analysis (à la CGEL) !!. Btw, like you, I'd call it a VP (or part of one).

Comment: Remain steadfast, SB, and refuse to bow down to CGELism. Only give the complete CGEL treatment if you add other flavours for balance.

Comment: Okay I'll impart this knowledge to my teacher because she wasn't sure about it either. Thanks for that. Do you know about Phrase Structure Analysis? I kinda have a doubt but I know I'm asking too much :)

Comment: @BillJ I'm between theologies right now, so I'll leave close exegesis to those of you who are more secure in your faith.

Comment: @ShonimaNandakumar I know *some* about PS, but the deeper I get into it the more often it seems to drive toward modes of analysis I'm uncomfortable with. I'm playing around with Construction Grammar these days--but don't ask me about that, 'cause I'm just beginning!

Comment: Okay then... Thanks alot for all your help! Very glad I asked the question. Lots of love. ✌